# Why correct response not coming after data insert in Node?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, crud

I am trying to do a insert operation using Node but the problem is the data is getting inserted in database but also throwing an error. Below is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const db = require('../models/database');
const adminUser = db.AdminUser;
const errors = require('../config/errors').errors;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

exports.signUp = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12).then(hash => {
        const admin = new adminUser({
            emailId: req.body.emailId,
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            middleName: req.body.middleName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            mobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
            userName: req.body.userName,
            password: hash,
            role: req.body.role,
            createdBy: req.body.createdBy
        });
        admin.save().then(result => {
            return res.status(200).send(error.OK);
        }).catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).send(error.SERVER_ERROR);
        });
    });
};
```

Here instead of the `then` block the `catch` block is getting fired and throwing this error:

```
{
  emailId: 'abc@gmail.c',
  firstName: 'Avishek',
  middleName: '',
  lastName: 'Ray',
  mobileNumber: '123-456-7890',
  userName: 'avishek12',
  password: 'abc123',
  role: 'admin',
  createdBy: 'avi'
}
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `admin_users` (`id`,`emailId`,`firstName`,`middleName`,`lastName`,`mobileNumber`,`userName`,`password`,`role`,`createdBy`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
(node:17380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at D:\practice\otp\frontend\backend\controller\auth.controller.js:25:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:17380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17380) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please help me !!

Comment: It's 2020 so for your own health and welfare, use `async` functions with `await`, not the antiquated `then` model.

Comment: This is a typo. You call your variable `err` then reference `error`. When you see a "not defined" error, look extremely closely at your code.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: @tadman the `.then()` also has a reference to `error.OK`. There is a require for `errors` so maybe it's a typo?

Comment: @doublesharp Ah, good spot, yeah `errors` vs `error`.

Comment: thanks all yeah that was a typo problem :(

Comment: and @tadman thanks for the suggestion of using ```async```, ```await```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your use of constants it looks like you should be using `errors` (with an S) in your `.then()` and `.catch()`.

```
const errors = require('../config/errors').errors;

// ... code


    admin.save().then(result => {
        // reference errors require
        return res.status(200).send(errors.OK);
    }).catch(err => {
        // reference errors require
        return res.status(500).send(errors.SERVER_ERROR);
    });
```

To write this with `async/await`:

```
exports.signUp = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12);
        const admin = new adminUser({
            emailId: req.body.emailId,
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            middleName: req.body.middleName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            mobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
            userName: req.body.userName,
            password: hash,
            role: req.body.role,
            createdBy: req.body.createdBy
        });
        await admin.save();
        return res.status(200).send(errors.OK); 
    } catch (err) {
        // console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(errors.SERVER_ERROR);
    }
};
```